# Assign data from REST YOUTUBE DATA API 3 to a variable outside callback Function Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, youtube-data-api, jquery-callback

Problem: I want to get the data from the REST API call and assign it to a variable and use that as an input for another Function or Purpose.

Function:

```
function getSongName(id, callback) {
        var apikey = {My_TOKEN};
        var fetchInformation = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=" +apikey +"&fields=items(snippet(title" +"))&part=snippet&id=" +id;
        $.getJSON(fetchInformation, function (jsonData) {
            fullname = jsonData.items[0].snippet.title;
            callback(fullname);
        });
    }
```

I am calling this function in another place with

```
var title = getSongName(youtubeID, function(name) {
                                    console.log("song name is :"+name);
                                });
```

I get the value in console.log as required.
Now I want to use this title in

```
z.innerHTML = '<b>' + title + 'num: ' + j + '</b>';
```

Here `j` is coming from another place so I cannot use it inside the "getSongName" call.

Is there a way not just to do `console.log` inside but actually assign the "name" to another variable and use it as what I want above?

I don't know if there is another way of doing this that I have not come across but any help will be appreciated.

**SOLVED -----------STEPS MENTIONED BELOW**

```
function getSongName(youtubeID, idForPlayer,i, z, callback) {
    var apikey = {My_TOKEN};
    var fetchInformation = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=" +apikey +"&fields=items(snippet(title" +"))&part=snippet&id=" +id;

//$.ajaxSetup({'async':false}); WILL return the value for each loop and not do it asynchronously which had me pulling my hair out. P.S. this was the reason only one value was being returned
$.ajaxSetup({'async':false});
        $.getJSON(fetchInformation, function (jsonData) {
            debugger;
            var fullname = jsonData.items[0].snippet.title;
            boolean = false;
            if (fullname) {
                boolean = true;
                if (boolean){
                    console.log("song name inside the gerSongName loop is: " + i +" ", fullname);
                    callback(fullname);
                }
                debugger;
            }
            else {
                debugger;
                console.log("No song name");
            }

        });
    }
```

Then inside another function which is run in a loop I called the above function to get me the value.

```
getSongName(youtubeID, idForPlayer,i, z, function(name) {
                                    z.innerHTML = '<b>' + name + '</b>';
                                    debugger;
                                    document.getElementById('elementTagID').appendChild(z);

                                });
```

Hope this helps someone else. 
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You could put outside of the function a var declaration like this:

```
var fullname = "";

function getSongName(id, callback) {
        var apikey = {My_TOKEN};
        var fetchInformation = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=" +apikey +"&fields=items(snippet(title" +"))&part=snippet&id=" +id;
        $.getJSON(fetchInformation, function (jsonData) {
            fullname = jsonData.items[0].snippet.title;
            callback();
        });
    }
```

But the call is async, so the var only gets value after callback.If I understood the question.. I think it's more right to use callback directly like you do for logging.

Comment: Thank you. and where would you put this `z.innerHTML = '<b>' + title + 'num: ' + j + '</b>';` ?

Also where is the data assigned to `fullname` ?

Comment: Should be inside a function on callback, like you do for logging. In my sample I'll put that line inside the function that is passed when call getSongName.. Like this: getSongName(1, function () { z.innerHTML = '<b>' + title + 'num: ' + fullname + '</b>'; }); But fullame is still available for other use outside that callback function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably take a different approach and change the structure to this:

```
z.innerHTML = '<b><span class="title"></span>num: ' + j + '</b>';
```

And then in your callback:

```
document.querySelector('.title').textContent = name;
```

Or for browsers that don't support textContent:

```
document.querySelector('.title').innerHTML = name;
```

See the following plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/k5Evt98M5fiOazU7tpKU

Comment: This could work but the problem is, Im making this `z.innerHTML` dynamically so if I apply your solution, only the last name out of many names will get printed. Also take into account, I want the `j` to be dynamic aswell.

Comment: Ok, it's a bit difficult without seeing the rest of your code, but I've made a plunk here - https://plnkr.co/edit/k5Evt98M5fiOazU7tpKU - to demonstrate my code, maybe this will help. I'm not sure why you say only the last name will get printed out but maybe you have a loop running somewhere that we're not seeing.

Comment: Thank you Chris :)
I got it working finally!! So what I did was instead of taking the data out of the function I injected other data into the function and did the deed inside it.

I will update my initial question to show what I did for references. Might help others save hours of work. 

Thank you all!!